# How to show limited rows in a section of a table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Let's say i have two sections in a table, section 1 has 800 reusable cells in it. How can we set the section that it should display 10 cells at a time and when I click show more button, it should load the next 10 cells and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part from your question:

> section 1 has 800 reusable cells in it

Looks like you have 800 rows in section 1 instead of 800 cells. Once you render tableview it will only create cells that can be displayed on screen and will reuse them once more data comes.

You need to do the following:

1. Create a main datasource (say array) containing 800 rows. (say `allRows`)
2. Create another source which contains partial data from `allRows`. (say 'fetchedRows')
3. Add a `Load More` button in either footer or in last row.
4. On Pressing 'Load More' fetch some number of rows from `allRows` to `fetchedRows`. (say 10 rows)
5. Reload table view using data source `fetchedRows`.
6. Same steps can be followed for section 2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`

use the section.

`if section == 0
    return 100
 else if section == 1
    return 10`

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps :

set in global:

```
var arrIndex = 10
```

Then in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrIndex

}
```

Then add button on bottom of table View. In the button action please write

```
 @objc func btnShowMoreClicked(sender : Any){
    arrIndex = arrIndex + 10
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

It may helps you. Thank you.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage this things using `pageIndex` set the global variable `var pageIndex:Int = 1` and tap more to increment `pageIndex` by 1 and reload `UITableview`

I have written this logic for section 0 initially load 10 records,

I have add one row more by **+1** in this statement `return (10 * pageIndex) + 1` because +1 is for load more button.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
        if section == 0 {
            return (10 * pageIndex) + 1
        }else {
            return 10
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

First Set Global int Variable :

```
@interface TableViewController () {

    int arrNum;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrNum = 3;

}
```

Then set the Sections Counts :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0){
        return arrNum;
    }else {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Then Create a Button in the footer of the section :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [btn setTitle:@"btn Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClk) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    return btn;
}
```

now set the Action you need when the Button clicked :

```
-(void)btnClk {

    arrNum = arrNum + 2;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });

}
```